# Obtain frequency spectrum for four basic signals using simulink blocks

Tags: simulink, spectrum

I tried using the 'Spectrum Analyzer' and those signal blocks (sine, pulse generator, triangle generator and sawtooth generator) separately of course, but the spectrum block needs a discrete signal or a non-infinite signal, and there's only a discrete sine block, is there a way to generate the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most input blocks, including those you list, have a `Sample Time` parameter.  Make it a number greater than 0 to specify a discrete sample time.  For instance 0.001 would give you a milli-second sample rate.

For the few blocks that don't have this, simply use a [Zero-Order Hold](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/zeroorderhold.html) on the output of the block, and specify a sample time for the ZOH block.